# How do I output a result of an each statement to a variable?

Tags: ruby, string

I have this code that prints each character of a string twice:

```
r = "12345"
r.split("").each do |ch|
  puts "#{ch}#{ch}"
end
```

I get this output:

```
11
22
33
44
55
```

I want to store the output `"1122334455"` in a variable. How do I rewrite the code to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
r.gsub(/(.)/,'\1\1') #=> "1122334455"
```

Comment: Nice way to do it.

Comment: @Natalia You could also write `'\1'*2` for the substitution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use chars to get each character in the string as a value in a "main" array, then using map format the elements inside, and then join all of them to make a final string, like:

```
r = '12345'
capture = r.chars.map { |ch| ch * 2 }.join
p capture
# "1122334455"
```

Comment: You could also interpolate with `"#{ch*2}"`:)

Comment: I wanted something like `r.chars.map(&2.method(:*))` but it doesn't work that way :c

Comment: I already accepted teh answer but as a note I ran a performance test with Rails.benchmark and this actually runs faster than the ansewr I accepted.

Comment: Really Sawa's answer is the fastest one, you could add it to your benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

Sagar and Sebastian's answers are the straightforward way to do this, but if you want to stick to your original code (iterate over the characters), then this is another way:

```
variable = r.each_char.with_object(""){|c, s| s << c * 2}
# => "1122334455"
```

Comment: `r.each_char.with_object` may be a further refinement.

Comment: @SagarPandya Right. That would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#sum` in Ruby > 2.4

```
'12345'.chars.sum('') { |n| n * 2  }                                           
 #=> "1122334455"
```